# Subtraction over a list of sets

Tags: python, algorithm, list, set, list-comprehension

Given a list of sets:

```
allsets = [set([1, 2, 4]), set([4, 5, 6]), set([4, 5, 7])]
```

What is a pythonic way to compute the corresponding list of sets of elements having no overlap with other sets?

```
only = [set([1, 2]), set([6]), set([7])]
```

Is there a way to do this with a list comprehension?

Comment: Related: [Replace list of list with "condensed" list of list while maintaining order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13714755/4279)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To avoid quadratic runtime, you'd want to make an initial pass to figure out which elements appear in more than one set:

```
import itertools
import collections
element_counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(allsets))
```

Then you can simply make a list of sets retaining all elements that only appear once:

```
nondupes = [{elem for elem in original if element_counts[elem] == 1}
            for original in allsets]
```

---

Alternatively, instead of constructing `nondupes` from `element_counts` directly, we can make an additional pass to construct a set of all elements that appear in exactly one input. This requires an additional statement, but it allows us to take advantage of the `&` operator for set intersection to make the list comprehension shorter and more efficient:

```
element_counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(allsets))
all_uniques = {elem for elem, count in element_counts.items() if count == 1}
#                                                     ^ viewitems() in Python 2.7
nondupes = [original & all_uniques for original in allsets]
```

Timing seems to indicate that using an `all_uniques` set produces a substantial speedup for the overall duplicate-elimination process. It's up to about a [3.5x speedup](http://ideone.com/NUApHy) on Python 3 for heavily-duplicate input sets, though only about a [30% speedup](http://ideone.com/8b70l4) for the overall duplicate-elimination process on Python 2 due to more of the runtime being dominated by constructing the Counter. This speedup is fairly substantial, though not nearly as important as avoiding quadratic runtime by using `element_counts` in the first place. If you're on Python 2 and this code is speed-critical, you'd want to use an ordinary `dict` or a `collections.defaultdict` instead of a `Counter`.

Another way would be to construct a `dupes` set from `element_counts` and use `original - dupes` instead of `original & all_uniques` in the list comprehension, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093930/2357112) by munk. Whether this performs better or worse than using an `all_uniques` set and `&` would depend on the degree of duplication in your input and what Python version you're on, but it [doesn't](http://ideone.com/ugvQdw) [seem](http://ideone.com/7ddxZA) to make much of a difference either way.

Comment: Certainly a better way. Some links for the OP 1. [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) 2. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Literal syntax could be a little nicer with [{elem for elem in original...}]

Comment: @munk: Oh, right. I keep forgetting to use set literals and set comprehensions.

Comment: Intersecting with unique elements is about 6x faster than subtracting duplicates on my real world data set. In my dataset, the unique elements are rare and the duplicates are plentiful.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it can be done but is hardly pythonic

```
>>> [(i-set.union(*[j for j in allsets if j!= i])) for i in allsets]   
[set([1, 2]), set([6]), set([7])]
```

Some reference on sets can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). The `*` operator is called [unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: eww agreed. Avoid this like the plague. Prefer some verbose for loops (but great work Bhargav!)

Comment: You don't need the inner list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You'd prefer a genexp there?

Answer (score 6):

A slightly different solution using Counter and comprehensions, to take advantage of the `-` operator for set difference.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

allsets = [{1, 2, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 7}]
element_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(allsets))

dupes = {key for key in element_counts 
         if element_counts[key] > 1}

only = [s - dupes for s in allsets]
```

Comment: I actually thought about that after I posted my original solution, though I used `&` and made a `unique_elements` set instead of a `dupes` set. [Timing](http://ideone.com/8b70l4) showed `&` to be about 30% faster than running a Python-level set comprehension every time. Whether `&` or `-` performs better probably depends on the degree of element duplication and what Python version you're on.

Comment: Selecting this solution as the best answer because 1) it is very readable, 2) 15%-30% faster than the user2357112 solution on my real world data

Comment: Very nice and readable solution.  I originally selected this as the best answer based on readability and speed.  Later changed to user2357112's answer, which upon further testing is significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x - set(chain(*(y for y in allsets if y!=x))) for x in allsets]
[set([1, 2]), set([6]), set([7])]
```

Also doable without the unpacking and using `chain.from_iterable` instead.