# How to find all pairs of sets (in a collection) that share at least M elements?

Tags: algorithm, set

Given a large set of sets, all the same size (call it *S={s<sub>1</sub>,...,s<sub>n</sub>}*), I want to find all pairs (*s<sub>i</sub>,s<sub>j</sub>)* that have an overlap of at least *M*.

So if *M=2* and *S* consists of

- s<sub>1</sub> = (3,4,8,9)

  s<sub>2</sub> = (1,3,7,8)

  s<sub>3</sub> = (1,2,5,6)

  s<sub>4</sub> = (1,6,7,8)

I want to identify the pairs (s<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>), (s<sub>2</sub>,s<sub>4</sub>), and (s<sub>3</sub>,s<sub>4</sub>).

The straightforward approach compares every pair and checks for the size of the intersection, but this is prohibitively slow given the number of sets and size of sets I am using (something like *O(log(m) n<sup>2</sup>)* where *m* is the size of the sets?).

I've searched around and haven't found a similar question (though [this answer is probably relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312912/algorithm-for-merging-sets-that-share-at-least-2-elements)). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your naive approach will run in *O(m n^2)* so time complexity would even be worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Go by value**

pseudo code:

```
typedef V => type of values;

list<Set> S;
Map<V, list<int>> val2sets;
for(int setIdx=0; setIdx < S.length; ++setIdx){
    foreach(V v in S[setIdx]) {
        val2sets[v].push(setIdx);
    }
}

int[][] setIntersectCount;
foreach(V as v ,list<int> as l in val2sets) {
    for(int i=0; i < l.length; ++i){
        for(int j=i+1; j < l.length; ++j){
            setIntersectCount[i][j]++;
            if(setIntersectCount[i][j] == 2){
                printf("set {0} and {1} are a pair\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as for Complexity:

let S = # of sets.
let M = # of members in a set.
let V = # of unique values in the sets.

`O(SM)` generating the val2sets

as for reading all values and matching each 2...,
it is maxed at O(V x S^2) but probability it will be closer to `O(SM)` because uniformity will say not all sets will have all elements in common.

P.S. hope i didn't have any mistake in my calculations.

Worth to note: I did not calculate the Naieve approach complexity either :)

Comment: Yes, this seems like a much better approach. Thanks!